# Get values from a list of dictionaries in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Okay, so I have a dataframe. Each element of column 'z' is a list of dictionaries.

For example, row two of column 'z' looks like this:

```
[ {'name': 'Tom', 'hw': [180, 79]},
  {'name': 'Mark', 'hw': [119, 65]} ]
```

I would like it to just contain the 'name' values, in this case the element would be Tom and Mark without the 'hw' values.

I've tried converting it into a list, then removing every second element, but I lost which values came from the same row. Not every row has the same number of elements in it, some have 2 names, some might have 4.

Comment: Maybe `df['name'] = [[d.get('name') for d in x] for x in df['z']]` ..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way using [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

#### Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'z': [[{'name': 'Tom', 'hw': [180, 79]},
                         {'name': 'Mark', 'hw': [119, 65]}]]})

df['name'] = [[d.get('name') for d in x] for x in df['z']]
```

[out]

```
                                                   z         name
0  [{'name': 'Tom', 'hw': [180, 79]}, {'name': 'M...  [Tom, Mark]
```

Comment: alternative list comprehension using apply that is a little bit more readable: `df['z'].apply(lambda x: [d['name'] for d in x])`

Comment: that's a much slower alternative - you should generally use list comprehension over `apply` method if you can

Comment: Of course it is going to be slower...it uses `apply` i simply said it is a little bit easier to read.

Comment: Not sure I agree, but It is subjective... I don't think introducing `lambda` improves readability necessarily - you could add it as an alternative solution however

Answer (score 4):

Let us use `pandas` `get`  using [`series.str.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html)

```
df['name']=df.col.str.get('name')
df
                                 col  name
0   {'name': 'Tom', 'hw': [180, 79]}   Tom
1  {'name': 'Mark', 'hw': [119, 65]}  Mark
```

Comment: I think it's one row, with a list of dicts, not 2 rows with 1 dict each

Comment: @ChrisA I am not sure `row two of column 'z' `

Comment: Yes, "For example, row two of column 'z' looks like this" .... that is referring to the value of 1 cell in DataFrame no? ie `df.loc[1, 'z']`

Comment: Also, clue is in the title `"Get values from a list of dictionaries in a Pandas Dataframe"`